# Passing JSON into MVC Controller - returns always null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

we are using MVC 2 on our project.

am getting null value for the object which is sent to controller using jquery/json

please correct me where i made the mistake.

here is my code

on posting data to controller i wrote below JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#frmContact").submit(function () {
                    x = '{"Name":"John","EmailAddress":"john@gmail.com"}';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/dashboard/gmail',
                        data: x,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                        });
             });
});
```

Note: i tried `JSON.stringify(x)` also for the data.

on the controller part i wrote:

```
public class ContactDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ObjectFilter(Param = "contactDetail", RootType = typeof(ContactDetail))]
public ActionResult gmail(ContactDetail contactDetail)
{
    // for now i didn't wrote any code here
    return View();
}
```

### contactDetail is null.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC 2 didn't come with a json value provider as standard. Take a look at this [Phil Haack blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) to explain how to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
x = {"Name":"John","EmailAddress":"john@gmail.com"};
```

?

Comment: just now i tried. but i didn't get the result. if i remove the single Quotes. x value show [Object object] in alert.